# Can I get the database login/password in an action?

Tags: symfony1, pdo

I have a symfony action that creates a mysqldump of the database :

```
public function executeBackup(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $dump = `mysqldump -u root -proot ec2`;
    $fp = fopen("php://temp", 'r+');
    fputs($fp, $dump);
    rewind($fp);

    $this->setLayout(false);
    header('Content-Type: application/gzip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="db.sql"');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $this->fichier = stream_get_contents($fp);
}
```

I've written the database login and password (root/root) in the action, but how can I get them from the yml configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [the code of this plugin](http://svn.symfony-project.com/plugins/sfMySQLDumpPlugin/lib/task/mysql/sfMySQLDumpTask.class.php), it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I've been tring to recreate :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this answer on the old Symfony forum](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.symfony.users/4210).

So retrieving **login** and **password** from **databases.yml** should look like:

```
$file = sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir').'/databases.yml';
$config = file_exists($file) ? sfYaml::load($file) : array();

$db_params = $config['prod']['propel']['param']; // should follow the databases.yml structure
$username = $db_params['username'];
$password = $db_params['password'];
```

HTH